# How to add a default Text at the start of the multiline React Native TextInput

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, multiline, textinput

I'm trying to implement the replying input in React Native and I'd like to have a possibility to render the person name I want to reply to at the start of my reply text. I attached the example image. This Input will be multiline and it's important because I was thinking about adding some padding for my reply TextInput and just absolutely position the Person Name text at the padded space.
It looks like a possible solution but:

1. How to do it if we have multiline Text? if we add some padding for the TextInput it will affect all lines when I need only the first one
2. The person name text could have various width so the padding value shouldn't be hardcoded. I think it could be solved by just rendering the Person name text first, calculating its width, and the set the padding for the TextInput but even in this case we'll face the issue 1)

Is it possible to achieve this feature somehow?

Thanks for any help!

[image: Example]

[image: EExample 2]

Answer (score 0):

You could have a nested style.

```
<Text style={styles.username}>@Rosemary#9234<Text style={styles.body}>I agree with you!</Text></Text>
```

Comment: Hi Robert. Thanks for your answer but how can it help with TextInput? I don't work with the simple Text but with the TextInput